# Legacy pairing, SSP - enable from command line [Linux]

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

As part of my automation project, I have two USB dongles and I need to automate the bluetooth test-cases. Both the devices seem to support SSP. This I infer from the hciconfig output. For ex: typing $hciconfig hci0 sspmode
I get,

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    Simple Pairing mode: Enabled
```

and I get a similar output for hci1. My questions are as follows:
a) How do I make them do SSP from command line [with and without encryption]?
b) How do I make them pair using legacy pairing method from command line [with and without encryption]?

For both #a and #b, how do I validate that indeed SSP and legacy pairing have happened using hcidump [if someone can point me to what to expect from the hci logs, I Would be very thankful.

Comment: Are you sure this is a core-bluetooth question? You seem to be using classic bluetooth but core-bluetooth is about bluetooth low energy.

Comment: @samprat tags on SO are quite important and I wasn't sure that this is a core-bluetooth question and comments are the only way to get in touch with the poster. This comment has been here for months without any response, so I'll simply retag if you have no concerns either. I just wanted to be correct. Thanks for the insightful comment, though. You  made my day and you surely helped Daylite just as much as I did. :)